# fit ImageView into background picture

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am kinda new with all this android. And I wanna create a simple app. I got a problem at fiting ImageView into background. I don't really know how to start with it. Also I wanna be sure all this fit to any screen size ( mostly phone, tablets not so important ).

Let say for example I have [image: This]  - this image as background. I wanna fit 2 of ImageView where the numbars are ( one where is 20 and one where is 14 ). And then I wanna insert my own images into this ImageView's and change them with `imageView.setImageResource();`

May someone help me ? I have no idea how should I start with all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in case someone else will have same question. Here is how I did it. I used ConstraintLayout.

I actually put this image into imageView and not in background. Then I added a linear-layout inside it. And put into 2x ImageView. Then I assign constraits from linearlayout to my big imageview(background) and this imageview(background) to end of screen like you can see it on pictures. It works as I wanted to.

Linear-layout constraints to imageview

[image: Linear-layout constraints to imageview]

ImageView(Background) constraints to screen

[image: ImageView(Background) constraints to screen]

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is going to be very hard to do what you want because to place an image in the black area, you will need to know it's coordinates, which will vary depending on the device. One trick might be to chop the clock image in 3 parts... the part that should always be to the left of the number, the part that will always be above the number, and the rest of the image. Then you can use a relative layout to align your inserted number image relative to the chopped up parts. The other approach of trying to estimate the coordinates regardless of device will probably be very hard.

Comment: Is there any tutorial or something for this ? How should I start ? I am really newbi at this

Comment: The easiest will be to use the layout gui and to play around with the positioning options there to see what all of the options are.

Comment: Technically it is called the "Layout Editor" in Android Studio. You can google around for a tutorial on that if you have never used it before. That will be the easiest place for a beginner to start.

Comment: Thank you. Will look at it. One more question if I may. Is there any tool to resize images for all drawable ? ( ldpi/mdpi/hdip/xdpi) Insted of using gimp multy times. Or is there option in android studio to do so ?

Comment: When you create the project, you can usually provide a high resolution  image that it will resize for all drawables.  I don't know how to do it otherwise

Comment: I would post that as a new question so that somebody else can help

Answer (score 0):

Using Custom View will be the best decision. Your class can extend ImageView or LinearLayout (RelativeLayout) and add your own methods to write (or more correct to draw) your own values. Android Studio IDE provides possibility to create templates for different screen sizes including images, text etc.